How to use Winapi.Dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute API for rounded window corners with Delphi 2007
I found this excellent source code for Delphi XE to make form windows rounded.
How can I convert this code to work with Delphi 2007 and older? It does not compile properly.
My executable also needs to remain compatible with Windows 7 and 8, do I need to call this DLL dynamically to avoid issues with Win7?
unit delphi_rounded_corners;

interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows;

type TRoundedWindowCornerType = (RoundedCornerDefault, RoundedCornerOff, RoundedCornerOn, RoundedCornerSmall);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Originally written by Ian Barker
//            https://github.com/checkdigits
//            https://about.me/IanBarker
//            ian.barker@gmail.com
//
// Based on an example in an answer during the RAD Studio 11 Launch Q & A
//
//
// Free software - use for any purpose including commercial use.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Set or prevent Windows 11 from rounding the corners or your application
//
// Usage:
//         SetRoundedCorners(Self.Handle, RoundedCornerSmall);
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
procedure SetRoundedCorners(const TheHandle: HWND; const CornerType: TRoundedWindowCornerType);


implementation
uses
  Winapi.Dwmapi;

const

  //
  // More information:
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute
  //

  DWMWCP_DEFAULT    = 0; // Let the system decide whether or not to round window corners
  DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1; // Never round window corners
  DWMWCP_ROUND      = 2; // Round the corners if appropriate
  DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3; // Round the corners if appropriate, with a small radius

  DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33; // [set] WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, Controls the policy that rounds top-level window corners

procedure SetRoundedCorners(const TheHandle: HWND; const CornerType: TRoundedWindowCornerType);
var
  DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE: Cardinal;
begin
  case CornerType of
    RoundedCornerOff:     DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_DONOTROUND;
    RoundedCornerOn:      DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_ROUND;
    RoundedCornerSmall:   DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL;
  else
    DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_DEFAULT;
  end;
  Winapi.Dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(TheHandle, DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, @DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, sizeof(DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE));
 end;
end.


What does "It does not compile properly" mean exactly? Any error messages?

Why it doesn't compile? What is the error? Also are you aware that rounder window corners is a feature that is limited to Windows 11 only. This means you will have to make sure your code checks the Windows version before executing otherwise you are risking undefined behavior.

Winapi.Windows is not available in D2007

Yes, I prefer a solution that would not cause any risks for Win7...10 users

Unit WinApi.Windows was just Windows in Delphi 2007.


How can I convert this code to work with Delphi 2007 and older? It does not compile properly.

Unit Scope Names were introduced in XE2. In order versions, simply drop the Winapi. prefix. In fact, you can do anyway even in modern Delphi versions, as Winapi is typically configured in a project's Unit Scope Names list by default. And if it is not, you can easily add it.
The DwmApi unit does exist in Delphi 2007.
Also, you should be using Windows.DWORD instead of Cardinal.
Try this:
unit delphi_rounded_corners;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  TRoundedWindowCornerType = (RoundedCornerDefault, RoundedCornerOff, RoundedCornerOn, RoundedCornerSmall);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Originally written by Ian Barker
//            https://github.com/checkdigits
//            https://about.me/IanBarker
//            ian.barker@gmail.com
//
// Based on an example in an answer during the RAD Studio 11 Launch Q & A
//
//
// Free software - use for any purpose including commercial use.
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Set or prevent Windows 11 from rounding the corners or your application
//
// Usage:
//         SetRoundedCorners(Self.Handle, RoundedCornerSmall);
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
procedure SetRoundedCorners(const TheHandle: HWND; const CornerType: TRoundedWindowCornerType);

implementation

uses
  Dwmapi;

const

  //
  // More information:
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute
  //      https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute
  //

  DWMWCP_DEFAULT    = 0; // Let the system decide whether or not to round window corners
  DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1; // Never round window corners
  DWMWCP_ROUND      = 2; // Round the corners if appropriate
  DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3; // Round the corners if appropriate, with a small radius

  DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33; // [set] WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, Controls the policy that rounds top-level window corners

procedure SetRoundedCorners(const TheHandle: HWND; const CornerType: TRoundedWindowCornerType);
var
  DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE: DWORD;
begin
  case CornerType of
    RoundedCornerOff:     DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_DONOTROUND;
    RoundedCornerOn:      DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_ROUND;
    RoundedCornerSmall:   DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL;
  else
    DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := DWMWCP_DEFAULT;
  end;

  // or simpler, since TRoundedWindowCornerType and
  // the DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE enum have the
  // same numeric values:
  //
  // DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE := Ord(CornerType);

  Dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(TheHandle, DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, @DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, sizeof(DWM_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE));
end;

end.


My executable also needs to remain compatible with Windows 7 and 8, do I need to call this DLL dynamically to avoid issues with Win7?

Yes.  Fortunately, the DwmApi unit already handles that for you internally.  The DwmApi.DwmSetWindowAttribute() function dynamically loads DWMAPI.DLL and accesses the Win32 DwmSetWindowAttribute function at runtime, and it will return E_NOTIMPL if the API is not available.

Thank you, I can confirm that the code does compiles OK!
However, there is a weird issue that the height of my small window (height=100px, width=300px) changes when calling SetRoundedCorners()  to 300px, from rectangle to square. Any ideas, why this API does that?  It is not possible to change it smaller after calling this API.

@tom that is a new question which warrants its own post.

Sure, thank you a lot!

here you go; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79014559/rounding-the-corners-of-a-tooltip-window-with-dwm-window-corner-preference-makes
